# Card.io Cordova camera not showing in Card.io interface

Tags: cordova, card.io

I'm trying to implement Card.io in my Cordova application. I'm running the latest Cordova version 6.3.1 with iOS 10.0 installed on my device. The canScan function returns "true" and the Card.io interface pops up when I tap the scan button, but the camera seems to be disabled because it doesn't work. I've tried setting the noCamera option to false, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Other options like the hideCardIOLogo : false works.

The Card.io interface shows the block where the camera view is supposed to be, the "Cancel" button, and the "Enter Manual" button. Neither of the buttons work though. If I check the logs in Xcode an error message appears the moment I take the Scan button. The error: shows a bunch of gibberish codes and at the end of the line "Thread : signalSIGABRT

From a little googling, it seems that the error message says something isn't wired up correctly on the SDK's side?

Any ideas of what could be wrong?
Do I have to enable the camera? (I never got a pop-up asking to allow camera usage)
Do I have to add the camera plugin?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As per [card.io-Cordova-Plugin](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Cordova-Plugin) readme, it says

Note: For use with iOS 10 + When building your app with the iOS 10 SDK +, you have to add some info to the info.plist file. This is due to increased security in iOS 10. Go to your app directory and search for the Info.plist file. Add the following lines in the main  element.

```
  <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
  <string>To scan credit cards.</string>
```

I am also trying to get this to work, let me know how it goes for you, I will post back my result.